# Java: Using Printf to allign code?

Tags: java, formatting, printf

When using `Printf` in `Java`, How do you know what "-10", "-20" etc to use in order to `format` your output as readable as possible. E.g. in the following code:

```
System.out.printf("[%-10s] %-20s %-20s £%.2f","Employee",this.firstName, this.lastName, this.baseRate);
```

Is there a set Formula etc for what numbers to use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is documentation available that describes what each of the formatting options is for: [Java printf quick reference](http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf)

In summary (copied from the linked document):

**Format String:**

Composed of literals and format specifiers. Arguments are required only if there are format specifiers in the format string. Format specifiers include: flags, width, precision, and
conversion characters in the following sequence:

```
%[flags][width][.precision]conversion-character
```

(square brackets denote optional parameters)

**Flags:**

```
- : left-justify (default is to right-justify)
+ : output a plus (+) or minus (-) sign for a numerical value
0 : forces numerical values to be zero-padded ( default is blank padding )
, : comma grouping separator (for numbers > 1000)
  : space will display a minus sign if the number is negative or a space if it is positive
```

**Width:**

Specifies the field width for outputting the argument and represents the minimum number of characters to be written to the output. Include space for expected commas and a decimal point in the
determination of the width for numerical values.

**Precision:**

Used to restrict the output depending on the conversion. It specifies the number of digits of precision when outputting floating-point values or the length of a substring to extract from a String. Numbers are rounded to the specified precision.

**Conversion-Characters:**

```
d : decimal integer [byte, short, int, long]
f : floating-point number [float, double]
c : character   Capital C will upper case the letter
s : String      Capital S will uppercase all the letters in the string
h : hashcode    A hashcode is like an address. This is useful for printing a reference
n : newline     Platform specific newline character - use %n instead of \n for greater compatibility
```

Comment: Thanks, I was in particular wondering how the numbers work, i.e -10 etc, where is the start point etc to go in a - and + direction from?

Comment: `%-10s` means print a left justified string with minimum of 10 characters (right padding with spaces if less than 10 characters long).